# Thrust in space without expelling mass

Tags: conservation-laws, rocket-science, propulsion

The classic rockets move losing their mass in one direction and moving to the other direction.

Thinking about an alternative engine where we lose very small mass.

This is how the engine works

- The ball in the engine hits the front in a cycle.
- The ball is metal and it is controlled with software and magnets. ( Like maglev )
- The ball hits the front panel in a cycle and transfering its energy.
- The nuclear power source is losing its mass but relatively very small mass and it is converted into kinetic energy.
- The ball does not hit the back panel controlled by magnets.

So the general momentum says ;
m1v1=m2v2

if the mass is constant or decreasing very slowly. Can this craft accelerate in space where there is no friction ?

***How could we prove or disprove this ?***

[image]

Demo https://youtu.be/atVn_bgZjZA

Reference 
Maglev, Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev

Comment: You don't need a propulsion system to move. You need one to accelerate.

Comment: Certainly, the ball is moving in space...  Why the magnets? (Note that reliance of magnets to do magic physics is a strong indicator of a bad question). Explain how the ball gets back to the starting position without transferring momentum from the space craft back to the ball.

Comment: @JonCuster magnets

Comment: Accelerating the ball from the rear end towards the front would push the spacecraft backwards. When the ball strikes the front of the spacecraft, it would be accelerated forwards by the same amount. There is a net cancelling effect. You cannot move an object away from its centre of mass in space without exerting an external force. This being an internal force, it wouldn't work

Comment: @Jim - at least it is only two dimensions of magnets! Just imagine what four dimensions could do!

Comment: @joncluster the hit at the front will tranfer the balls energy. Than the magnets will take the ball back without hitting at the back. Than this process will cycle.

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin Regardless if the ball hits the back or not, as long as it is slowed or sped up by a part of the ship, momentum will transfer from the ball to the ship or vice versa. It never actually needs to hit the ship. It can be stopped by the magnetic field in all cases and this would work exactly the same way.

Comment: @jim how to prove or disprove is the question...

Comment: Prove or disprove what? That is the way physics is. Momentum is conserved. What you propose would violate momentum conservation if it actually moved the spacecraft. No more is necessary.

Comment: The momentum is conserved and the mass is lost in reaction and converted into kinetic energy.

Comment: No, that's not true. You have no external transfer of momentum that would allow the entire system to move from its centre of mass. Think about it. The ball-ship system has a centre of mass. To an outside observer, it's all one object. It can't spontaneously start moving without an external force transferring momentum into it. All it can do is reorient its shape while remaining on the centre of mass. The "mass loss" within the reactor is not the same as mass lost due to momentum transfer

Comment: Use that nuclear energy to propel balls to outside the space ship (open tube instead of closed tube, in the OP's schematic). Of course then it becomes a variant of a classic rocket expelling mass. OP's design as such doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

No, This device would just oscillate (vibrate)

When the first two electromagnets switched on the metal ball (which is presumably made out of a ferromagnet) would accelerate towards them but the craft would also accelerate towards the ball (At a lower acceleration as it has more mass). It would then switch to the next electromagnet pair and do the same thing. This would repeat until the ball reached the other side. When the ball collides with the side wall the momentum of the ball and craft will cancel eachother out.

If you switched to the penultimate electromagnet pair before the ball hit the side and repeated the process backwards (which is what I beleive you were suggesting) you would return the craft and the ball to their original location.

If you wanted to prove this you could do what NASA did with another design to produce thrust without expelling mass. Build the device, put it in a vacuum chamber on top of a device that can measure thrust (They used a low-thrust pendulum) and turn it on.

[Link to NASA paper](http://www.libertariannews.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/AnomalousThrustProductionFromanRFTestDevice-BradyEtAl.pdf) on testing an RF resonant cavity thruster (The results from this experiment are controversial but the way they tested the device is what I was referring to.)

*Edit: Corrected Link*

Comment: There is only one page. How could we get details about this ?

Comment: Will start from here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF_resonant_cavity_thruster

Comment: Sorry, looks like I linked to he abstract.

Comment: Found this also Watch "Full interview: Roger Shawyer, Creator of EmDrive" on YouTube
https://youtu.be/4hTdSg47h3k

Comment: Video presentation Watch "EmDrive Presentation by Roger Shawyer   Part 1 of 3 opt" on YouTube
https://youtu.be/GGTjy6atKMs   wished I had chance to work on this / learn it in detail

Comment: EmDrive and this concept is very different. Want to close the subject. But just not convinced at the answer as the thing is we can move on a skateboard even with the body movement. Took a stupid video to demonstrate. What is the flow here ? Reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JfZFNzlZR8

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good answers above, I'd like to add a point about the nuclear reactor losing mass.  It's true, it does, albeit at a really tiny rate.

The reason that this doesn't contribute to propulsion is that the mass is loss in all directions so the net effect is zero.

Comment: This does not lose mass www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JfZFNzlZR8 –

Comment: I can't watch that - it said "this video is private". Can you summarise it?

Comment: Essentially, though, the answer is still going to be the same. Conservation of momentum is an incredibly robust law. It's not a guideline.

Comment: Sorry updated the link and shared it. Could be missing a point and not critically thinking. But this breaks my reasoning. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JfZFNzlZR8

Comment: Thanks for updating the video.

That one's actually pretty easy to explain.  It's due to something called "stiction" or static friction.

Basically, friction is stronger when something is not moving.  Once it is moving, friction is reduced.  So as long as you move slowly on the skateboard, you won't set it moving.  Then when you move faster in the other direction, you overcome the friction and it moves.  Google "stiction".

Comment: So what happens is you jolt your tilt your body backward quickly.  The skateboard (and your feet) move forward, your head moves backwards.  On average your centre of mass stays stationary.

Then you very slowly move the other way.  Because the movement isn't fast enough to break the friction, you're essentially pushing against the ground very slowly to get yourself upright and move your centre of mass forward.

Comment: Then you repeat the process.  It looks like you're moving forward with no reaction, but actually you're pushing against the ground when you do the slow return.

Comment: Could not find the resource about stiction. Could you provide a reference ?

Comment: Just Google it.

Comment: Found this one but has issues.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiction